# how to wrap this function from C++ to Java with swig

Tags: java, c++, swig

```
bool func1(classA* A,int numberOfA,double (&result)[4]);
```

"A" is pointed to an array of classA

```
bool func2(double param4[4]);
```

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg "double (&result)[4]" here is for passing a parameter that is exactly 4 elements,and used for both input and output

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg this (&result)[4] arg can restrict input to a 4 elements array.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg To use this function,i first declare a double array:double param[4],other forms of declaration would'nt pass the compile.

Comment: Oh, I actually didn't know that, but it *does* make sense in a way. Just tried it out. :) Sorry